# Install Windows control panel applet in Wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, dll

I want to add the bthprops.cpl dll (The bluetooth control panel applet) to my wine install 
under Ubuntu 10.04 since it is required for Dolphin Emulator. http://www.dolphin-emulator.com/

I copied the file from my windows install into the System32 folder in .wine and into the
folder where the application I am trying to run is, but wine still fails to load it. Is
there anything else I need to do to make the dll accessible for wine programs?

(Please don't suggest the native linux Version of Dolphin as a fix - it is not working
for me)

Comment: Copy the file next to dolphin.exe, it worked for me

Comment: *ahem* XYProblem

Answer (score 3):

You can [download any .dll](http://www.dll-files.com/), then use `regsvr32` to register the file then launch it:

```
regsvr32 dll_file_to_register
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL controlApplet.cpl
```

For example:

```
wine rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL appwiz.cpl
```